# TensorFlow Dataset: Order appears randomised when iterating via For loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, for-loop, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am creating some batch TensorFlow datasets tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory:

```
image_size = (90, 120)
batch_size = 32

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    os.path.join(model_split_dir,'train'),
    validation_split=0.25,
    subset="training",
    seed=1,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    os.path.join(model_split_dir,'train'),
    validation_split=0.25,
    subset="validation",
    seed=1,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    os.path.join(model_split_dir,'test'),
    seed=1,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

If I then use the following for loop to get image and label information from one of the datasets, I get different outputs each time I run it:

```
for images, labels in test_ds:
  print(labels)
```

For instance, the first batch will appear like this in one run:

```
tf.Tensor([0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1], shape=(32,), dtype=int32)
```

But then be completely different when the loop is run again;

```
tf.Tensor([1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0], shape=(32,), dtype=int32)
```

How can the order be different every time I loop over it? Are TensorFlow datasets unordered? From what I've found, they are supposed to be ordered, so I have no idea why the for loop returns the labels in different orders each time.

Any insight regarding this would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: The shuffling of the order of the dataset is working as intended. For my test data, I just need to set shuffle to False. Many thanks @AloneTogether !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `shuffle` of `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` is set to `True` by default, if you want deterministic results, maybe try setting it to `False`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  image_size=(28, 28),
  batch_size=5,
  shuffle=False)

for x, y in train_ds:
  print(y)
  break
```

This, on the other hand, will always yield random results:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  seed=None,
  image_size=(28, 28),
  batch_size=5,
  shuffle=True)

for x, y in train_ds:
  print(y)
  break
```

If you set a random seed and `shuffle=True`, the dataset will be shuffled once but you will have deterministic results:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  seed=123,
  image_size=(28, 28),
  batch_size=5,
  shuffle=True)

for x, y in train_ds:
  print(y)
  break
```

Comment: I would have thought it would only shuffle once when I declare the train_ds dataset, is it purposfully reshuffling the dataset everytime I read it? I would have hoped declaring a seed would make the ordering deterministic and unchanging.

If I set shuffle to False, it sorts my data into alphanumeric order, which I don't think will work for my application since my validation dataset will then only has positive labels in it.

Comment: @Jimblim if you set a seed and `shuffle=True`, you should also be able to get the same results when iterating. I just wanted to point out to you that `seed` defaults to `None` and `shuffle` defaults to `True`, hence the random results. Does that make sense?

Comment: That was my initial understanding as well, but I am declaring a seed in my code above (with shuffle defaulting to True), and yet my results keep changing when iterate over the dataset, which I do not understand.

Comment: @Jimblim Can you run the last code snippet in my answer and see if you are getting the same results every time? I am running everything on google colab and it's working.

Comment: I've tried your snipit and yes, I am also getting the same results everytime. However, if I run the for loop again without declaring train_ds at the same time, the results come out different. This is interesting, because the initial value of train_ds seems to be the same when it is first declared, but upon accessing it later it changes, which is certainly not what I want.

Comment: Ah, yes I understand the problem, if you take a look at the source code, shuffling is done at every batch iteration: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/image_dataset.py#L224.. That explains the behavior you are seeing